# @RestClientTest with Application having configurations from external libs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have an spring boot app which is scanning packages from two external libs.

```java
Application.java

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({ "com.ext.lib.one", "com.ext.lib.two", "my.app.stuff" })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}


application.yaml
// properties from com.ext.lib.one configurations
config: 
  aud: 
  certificate: <value>
  ad: <value>
    policy: <value>
    aud: <value>
    configUrl: <value>
...
```

Now I want to have a test for a rest controller using `@RestClientTest`.

```java
MyClientTest.java

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(MyClient.class)
public class MyClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Autowired
    private MyClient client;

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {}

}
```

The test always complains about missing beans from the external libs (com.ext.lib.one, com.ext.lib.two) which are detected during component scanning.

How can I make this test work having an application context without the stuff from these external libs because they do not have auto-configuration enabled (these libs are mainly for authentication which I do not want to test).

**What I tried so far**

```java
MyClientTest.java

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@RestClientTest(MyClient.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.app.stuff"}, excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.ext\\.lib\\.one\\..*")))
// additionally
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {com.ext.lib.one.configuration.ExtConfiguration.class})
public class MyClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;

    @Autowired
    private MyClient client;

    @Test
    public void doSomething() {}

}
```

Still always the package *com.ext.lib.one* is scanned during test.

Comment: How do you set the properties when starting your application instead of via a unit test?

Comment: I tried it with an application-test.yaml and having @ActiveProfiles("test") in the Unit-test. Then one of the external libs wants to connect to kind of "auth service" what I do not want.

Comment: Without more info on how that extermal lib works, I don't think we can help.

Comment: This external lib is doing some authentication stuff. I has a configuration with url and some certificate information and validates user requests against an active directory. This I do not want to have in the test, therefore I thought adding @ComponentScan without the packages of this external lib will ignore this configuration.